how to run ssh in the background without writing my own OS kernel and SSH server/client pair?
So, this sounds like it "should" be possible.  But it takes some explaining.  Let me start from something simple.  Let's say I'm on some vaguely POSIX-like system (maybe GNU/Linux, maybe Cygwin, whatever).  I want a shell script that runs two commands and displays the output.  Easy:
#!/bin/bash
grep needle 1st-haystack.txt
grep needle 2nd-haystack.txt

Okay, now it turns out that this takes too long... let's try to run them in parallel as background jobs:
#!/bin/bash
grep needle 1st-haystack.txt > tmp1.txt &
grep needle 2nd-haystack.txt > tmp2.txt &
wait
cat tmp1.txt tmp2.txt
rm tmp1.txt tmp2.txt

A bit more complicated, but not bad.  But what if the command I want to run isn't grep?
What if, hypothetically, it's some command that can usually run with no interaction but once in a while needs to prompt the user for input?
In that case, when it tries to read from stdin while in the background, the terminal driver will notice that it's trying to read from the controlling terminal and send it a signal which will suspend it by default.  The shell will notice this and wait will return, and then the script can try to do something sensible about it.  For instance, something like this:
#!/bin/bash
# example below is suggestive and doesn't actually work else this would get too long
sleep 5 && cat > tmp1.txt &  # cat is our stand-in for a process that might need input
sleep 8 && cat > tmp2.txt &  # cat is our stand-in for a process that might need input
wait  # wait could return because we're "done" or because one of them needed input
cat tmp1.txt # so we figure out which case applies, and if one of them is stuck, then we cat
# what it wrote so far, so that the user has enough context to supply the input it needs.
fg  # then we bring it to the foreground, and don't try any more parallel tricks
# cleanup code and other stuff is omitted for brevity

So far so good!  Now let's try this over SSH.  First, the simple version:
#!/bin/bash
ssh box1 grep needle 1st-haystack.txt
ssh box2 grep needle 2nd-haystack.txt

This works of course.  Now in parallel:
#!/bin/bash
ssh box1 grep needle 1st-haystack.txt > tmp1.txt &
ssh box2 grep needle 2nd-haystack.txt > tmp2.txt &
wait
cat tmp1.txt tmp2.txt
rm tmp1.txt tmp2.txt

Still no problem!  Now let's bring back the complication of maybe needing input:
#!/bin/bash
# example below is suggestive and doesn't actually work else this would get too long
ssh box1 'sleep 5 && cat' > tmp1.txt &
ssh box2 'sleep 8 && cat' > tmp2.txt &
# uh-oh, now what?

It turns out that ssh has no way of knowing whether the remote process is trying to read input or not.  Thus, ssh needs to be ready to accept local input at all times.  But it can't call read() unconditionally, because then it would get suspended and the grep example above would not work.  So instead it poll()s to see if input is available from the local terminal, and if so THEN it read()s it.  When ssh is forced to run in the background, poll() never tells it that input is ready, so it never tries to read() it, so it never gets auto-suspended.  Thus the shell never gets any hints that the background job is stuck and will never get unstuck.
My question is, how much of the tech stack would one have to rewrite in order to get something like this to work?  Naively, it seems that this requires surgery across a lot of levels.

When cat on the remote server calls read(), the remote kernel knows that it is blocked waiting on its standard input.  However, the kernel tells no one about this.
If we had run ssh with -t then cat would have a controlling (pseudo-)terminal.  In that case, the kernel would know that sshd holds the master end of the pseudo-terminal.  Since we did not use -t, the standard input for cat is likely an ordinary pipe.  The kernel still knows that sshd holds the other end of that pipe.
Suppose that the kernel SOMEHOW had a way to tell sshd that cat wants more input.  This by itself does not help much, because as far as I know (which is not far) sshd has no standardized to report this info to the SSH client.
Let's suppose we control the SSH client AND server, and invent some non-standard way to convey this info that they both understand.
Then the SSH client can use this info to do an unconditional read(), which would get it suspended, so the shell finds out that it needs attention.

(And then we need to fix the weird issue where the terminal starts acting weird if I try to start ssh in the background and then bring it to the foreground.  That's likely just a mundane bug.)
(Oh, and also, at some point it would be nice to support non-POSIX ssh clients.  For instance, there's a nice one called plink which is part of the PuTTY suite.  Unlike PuTTY itself, it's a command-line tool with no GUI.  But unlike OpenSSH, it doesn't have work in terms of POSIX concepts like signals and terminals, since it's a native windows app.  But this is hard enough so let's ignore non-POSIX for now.)
My question is: is there an EASIER way to get this simple scenario to work, without the "rewrite the world" plan above?
